# Laravel setup on HostGator shared plan

Tags: php, laravel, shared-hosting

I'm trying to setup Laravel on a HostGator shared plan. I've followed these instructions:

http://laravel.io/forum/02-13-2014-how-to-install-laravel-on-a-hostgator-shared-server

I created and uploaded the .bashrc and .bash_profile files as instructed, then I run:

`source ~/.bashrc`

in the terminal, but then when I run `php -v` I get

> No such file or directoryphp

I also tried uploading an htaccess file with AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php to the root directory. When I run `phpinfo()` now, it shows php version 5.5.10, but php -v (before I run the source command) still shows version 5.2.17.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

## STEP 1 Copy your files

Copy your app in a **non-public** folder, example:

```
/home/foo/myapp
```

Move your public folder to a **public** folder, example:

```
/home/foo/public_html/public
```

Open your public/index.php file and change paths to reference your laravel non-public code, example:

```
require __DIR__.'/../../../myapp/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../../myapp/bootstrap/app.php';
```

## STEP 2 Change php version in Cpanel

For laravel 5.2 you need at least php 5.5

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation#server-requirements

[image: change php version]

this will add some lines in your .htaccess, for example, this will enable php7:

```
# Use PHP70 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php70/lib
</IfModule>
```

## STEP 3 Make artisan work

php command line may not work, run this command to check php version:

```
php -v
```

if it doesn't give you the correct version you may run your commands directly with php 5.6 binary, like this:

```
/opt/php56/bin/php artisan
```

## STEP 4 clear caches

Sometimes you need to clear your cache, there's two ways:

With artisan:

```
/opt/php56/bin/php artisan optimize
```

Manually:

Delete this two files

- bootstrap/cache/compiled.php
- bootstrap/cache/services.json

## How to use SSL

Hostgator shared servers have a shared SSL certificate

To use the shared SSL certificate you must access your public folder by the root of your server and your username like this:

https://gator1234.hostgator.com/~username

So for example, if you put your application in a folder called myapp it will become:

https://gator1234.hostgator.com/~username/myapp

this will mess the routes file, so you have to add this lines to your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~username/myapp
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote an article on how I was able to host my laravel 5.5 on a shared host. (Hostgator) 
https://www.5balloons.info/hosting-laravel-5-5-project-on-shared-hosting-hostgator/

Comment: link is broken!

Answer (score 0):

So there is one simple step that seems to get overlooked with most of the issues of setting up a subdomain to host a Laravel App using HostGator's Shared Hosting plan.

### HostGator Shared Server Hosting Plan

---

### Scenario:

***Domain:*** https://yardpenalty.com is pointing to the `home/username/public_html` folder which has a WordPress installation.

***Subdomain:*** https://games.yardpenalty.com is pointing to the `home/username/games/public` folder which has a Laravel App installation.

### Problem:

We want the Laravel App to be accessed at the Subdomain's root level...

**URI** at https://games.yardpenalty.com

**NOT** at https://games.yardpenalty.com/public.

### Solution:

**Step 1:**

Under our HostGator Shared Server Hosting Plan we can access the tools we need using cPanel.

**Step 2:**

In our cPanel we go-to **Domains->Subdomains** and we enter a name for our `Subdomain` (in this instance its called `games`).

**Step 3:**

Then we select a `Domain` from the dropdown list and in this scenario it is [yardpenalty.com](https://yardpenalty.com)  which is pointing to my `public_html` folder.

**Step 4:**

Finally, under the `Document Root /` (a.k.a. `home/user`) we point it to the `/games/public` folder!

It should look something like the second listing from your cPanel:

[image: HostGator's cPanel Subdomain list]

Answer (score -1):

I was finally able to get Laravel installed with some help from this:

http://shincoding.com/laravel/installing-configuring-laravel-shared-hosting/

Comment: link is broken!