# cannot deploy laravel application to subdomain in hostgator host

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, subdomain, cpanel

At the Beginning I would like to inform the reader that I have search a lot and tried many solutions but no one worked with me.

I have uploaded my public folder to public_html/subdomain folder, then I have edited the path for the vendor and the bootstrap in the index.php file. But it shows server error 500.

I tried to upload the same project files to other hosting with the same steps and it worked.

I guess that the problem is because .htaccess file but I am not sure and I don't know how to deal with it.

my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel setup on HostGator shared plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22897883/laravel-setup-on-hostgator-shared-plan)

Comment: Unfortunately no

Answer (score 0):

To deploy successfully laravel application you should follow some steps.

1. upload whole project to target directory
2. change some params in **.env** file
   i. `APP_DEBUG=true; APP_ENV=local`
3. delete everything from bootstrap/cache
4. refresh page

you will get errors in browser if anything occurred.  Then you should fix all of them step by step

Comment: I have tried it, not working